# Identifying when there is more than 1 in a group based on grouped field

Tags: t-sql

Sorry for the bad description it is tough to explain in one sentence.

I have a dataset that has Cause field (RootCause) and an ID field (GroupID).  Both can be many things but I need to identify where a GroupID has a multiple different rootcauses.

for example:
RootCause    GrpId 
AAA          111
BBB          222
CCC          111

I am looking to be able to identify that GrpId 111 has two different RootCauses.

This is what I have so far:

```
Select  [RootCause], GrpId, Count(GrpID) as CntGrpId
From DB.dbo.Table
Where DatatypeField <> ''
Group BY  [RootCause],GrpId
```

This results set visualy gives me enough information to identify what I am looking for, but i need something better.  I am looking to return only the ones that have multiples.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Look at `HAVING` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select  GrpId, distinct(RootCause) as CntGrpId
  From DB.dbo.Table
 Where DatatypeField <> ''
 Group BY  [RootCause],GrpId 
having count(distinct(RootCause)) > 1
```

this was accepted but I think it was wrong

```
Select  GrpId, count(distinct(RootCause))  as CntGrpId
  From DB.dbo.Table
 Where DatatypeField <> ''
 Group BY GrpId 
having count(distinct(RootCause)) > 1
```

Comment: perfect! I just had to revers the select order to have Distinct come first. But other wise this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks